# Foreign Keys with Composite Key

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, relational-theory, composite-types

Imagine I have a table with the following dependency:

> (**Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought**) --> Cost

Where the three attributes in bold form a composite primary key for the table. Now then, I want to link (form a relationship) from another table to this one. How do I do that? If I had an ID column I'd know what to do, but I've never come across a scenario like this.

Would I have to add all three columns `(Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought)` to the other table? Or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, you either add all 3 columns in the other table (and make the FK through those) or add a surrogate (ID) column in this one and make it unique (so you can make FKs to reference that).

Comment: Thanks ypercube. Is a surrogate ID column any different from a regular ID column? Or are we calling it "surrogate" just cause it isn't necessary to have?

Comment: Yep, that's what these columns are called. English is not my native language so no idea if that comes from "not necessary" or "doesn't have a meaning" or something else: [Surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you'd add all three columns. Assuming they have the same names in both tables, you'd use something like

```
foreign key (Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought) 
  references the_other_table_name (Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought)
```

If you decide to use a surrogate ID number, you'll still need a unique constraint on {Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought}.  You can do that with something along these lines.

```
create table your_table (
  your_id_number integer primary key,
  Name ... ,
  BoughtFrom ... ,
  TimeBought ... ,
  unique (Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought)
);
```

The surrogate key doesn't *have* to be an ID number. It doesn't have to be *any* kind of number. But an automatically incrementing ID number is the most common.

*Surrogate* means *takes the place of*. A surrogate key, like an ID number, takes the place of a natural key. Kind of like a surrogate mother takes the place of a natural mother.

Comment: Thanks Mike. The bit about enforcing a unique constraint was what I couldn't wrap my head around. How does one apply a unique constraint to a three way combination? i.e. all three values together must be unique? not just one value of each attribute. I hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: @Ciwan: Expanded my answer.