# Composite primary key from multiple tables / multiple foreign keys

Tags: foreign-key, oracle-11g, primary-key

I want to build a composite primary key made up of foreign keys from two different tables. I'm still pretty green to this...

A great answer was given to building a composite key from multiple foreign keys on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39023/25137) but I want to do this from multiple tables. I am using Oracle 11g.

```
foreign key (Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought) 
  references the_other_table_name (Name, BoughtFrom, TimeBought)
```

Imagine that the "references" line actually includes multiple tables. I'm not even sure that the above syntax will work with Oracle.

I have one table "Student" and one table "Parent". It is a many-to-many relationship. My association table is named "Relation" and I would like to make a composite primary key from "PAR_ID" and "STU_ID". Both are foreign keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short version:

```
CREATE TABLE Relation
( stu_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Student,
  par_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Parent,
  PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, par_id)
) ;
```

Long version:

- Why use short forms for names, like `stu_id` and `par_id`? Why not `student_id`? Saving typing 3-4 characters? How will you differentiate between parent_id and parameter_id? Or school_id and schoolmaster_id?
- The name `"Relation"` is not very descriptive for a relationship. (Note also that in relational model terminology, "relation" has a meaning very close to "table".) I couldn't come with a good name though, so we could use `"Guardian"` or `"Student_Parent"` (this combination is often used in intersection tables)
- The short version above is just an example. While it is working, it uses a lot of shortcuts, like the inline references. It's far better in my opinion, to name all constraints and declare all (primary, unique, foreign key and check) constraints after the column declarations, like in the long version below.
- It's also good to choose some naming conventions anduse them consistently in all the tables, e.g. `Tablename_PK` for the primary keys, `ReferencedTable_referencingTable_FK` for the foreign keys, `Something_UQ` for the unique constraints, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE Guardian
(                                        -- columns
  student_id INT NOT NULL, 
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
                                         -- constraints
  CONSTRAINT Guardian_PK                 -- the name of the PK constraint
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, parent_id),

  CONSTRAINT Student_Guardian_FK         -- the name of the FK constraint
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) 
    REFERENCES Student (student_id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE                  -- the actions of the FK
      ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT Parent_Guardian_FK          -- second FK
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
    REFERENCES Parent (parent_id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining some good practices in addition to the answer

Answer (score -4):

Foreign key it is a relationship between the two tables,Primary key is a not allow the duplicates and nulls.

Comment: This hardly constitutes an answer. Take the tour, visit the help centre and check out the "help us to help you" blog. Although it's mostly for asking questions, it is also of interest to people who answer them.